# Value of Zero sum game

Tags: game-theory

[image]

[image]

In part iii) I am unsure as to why we subtract 1 from the value of the game (underlined in green)

Comment: They changed the game from having payoff matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x&-1&-1\\-1&y&-1\\-1&-1&z\end{bmatrix}$ to instead having payoff matrix $\begin{bmatrix}x+1&0&0\\0&y+1&0\\0&0&z+1\end{bmatrix}$ since the strategies will be the same for each, and the second form is much nicer in that there are no negative numbers ensuring the technique used will work.  To account for every entry having value one more in the payoff matrix, the *value of the game* is one more than it would otherwise been, so we subtract one.

Comment: Why does the value of the game increase by 1?

Comment: Lets look at a small example.  If we have a simple game, we will call it game $G$, with only one choice for each player with payoff matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$ what is the value of the game?  It is $1$, right?  Now... if we change the payoff matrix by adding $5$ to each entry, the new game has payoff matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1+5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}6\end{bmatrix}$.  What is the value of this new game? In the same way, if we have a payoff matrix $M$, and we add $1$ to every entry, we have the new payoff matrix $M+[Ones]$.  If the original value was $m$, the new value is $m+1$

Comment: If you wish to prove the statement without relying on, for lack of better term, combinatorial interpretations, you may prove more rigorously that if $a$ is the row vector for player $A$'s optimal strategy for the original game, and $b$ is the row vector for player $B$'s optimal strategy, and $[Ones]$ is the appropriately sized matrix of all ones, and $M$ is the payoff matrix for the original game, and $v$ is the value of the original game, that $a$ and $b$ are the optimal solutions for the modified game with payoff matrix $(M+\lambda Ones)$ with value $v+\lambda$.  Hint, think of eigenvectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restate what I already said in the comments above:

The original game for part (iii) had payoff matrix: $M=\begin{bmatrix}x&-1&-1\\-1&y&-1\\-1&-1&z\end{bmatrix}$

We choose to consider a *different* game which is closely related to the original game but where instead all entries in the payoff matrix are non-negative.  To do so, we can choose to add one to every entry.  That is:

$M' = M+Ones_{3\times 3} = \begin{bmatrix}x+1&0&0\\0&y+1&0\\0&0&z+1\end{bmatrix}$

Worded without math, *whatever the result* of the game, we simply pay $A$ an additional dollar compared to what it would have originally been.  The strategy for $A$ and $B$ will not have changed, however in every instance, $A$ will end up with one more dollar than otherwise.  Therefore, if the original value of the game was $v$, the *new* value of the *modified game* is $v+1$.

Now, this new payoff matrix is very convenient for us because it very closely resembles the payoff matrix that you saw in part (ii) of the problem.  In part (ii), you saw that with payoff matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\color{green}{x} & 0&0\\0&\color{red}{y}&0\\0&0&\color{blue}{z}\end{bmatrix}$, the value of the game would be $\dfrac{\color{green}{x}\color{red}{y}\color{blue}{z}}{D}$ where $D$ is written as above in the image.

This implies that the value of the game with matrix $M' = \begin{bmatrix}\color{green}{x+1} & 0&0\\0&\color{red}{y+1}&0\\0&0&\color{blue}{z+1}\end{bmatrix}$ would be $v=\dfrac{\color{green}{(x+1)}\color{red}{(y+1)}\color{blue}{(z+1)}}{D'}$ where $D'$ is written as above in the image.

**However**, this is the value for the game with payoff matrix $M'$, i.e. the game where player $A$ got an extra dollar than they would have otherwise in every case.  It follows then that the value for the game with payoff matrix $M = M' - Ones_{3\times 3}$ will be $v-1$

---

For additional justification for why adding the $Ones$ matrix does not change the strategies of the game but changes the value of the game:

Suppose we have a game with payoff matrix $M$ and optimal strategies $a^*$ and $b^*$.

Then $a^* M b \geq a M b$ for all strategies $a$ and $b$ (including $b^*$).  Similarly $a M b^* \leq a M b$ for all strategies $a$ and $b$ (including $b^*$).

Now, note that $a (M+\lambda Ones)b = aMb + \lambda(a(Ones)b)$.  Note further what $(Ones)b$ is however.  As $b$ is a distribution vector, the sum of the entries of $b$ is one.  It follows that $(Ones)b$ is simply a vector of all ones.  It then follows that $a(Ones)b = a(Ones)=1$.

From here, we see that for all strategies $a$ and $b$, the value of the game with matrix $M+\lambda Ones$ is simply $\lambda$ plus the value of the game with matrix $M$ with the same strategies.  It follows then that $a^*$ and $b^*$ are still the optimal strategies.